# ASSERT: "i >= 0 && i < size()" in file Qt/6.2.4/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qstring.h

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

i am a noob in Qt, when a push a particular push button, the project window closes and shows this error:

> ASSERT: "i >= 0 && i < size()" in file Qt/6.2.4/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qstring.h

What is it? Is there something i can do to solve this?

Comment: it means that you are accesing a QString out of bounds somewhere in your code

Comment: For a start, extract a [mcve] as an exercise. This would probably have given you enough hints to see the error yourself. Another approach would have been to run the code in a debugger and to inspect the state when the error happens. Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.